# SharePoint 2013, unable to set property 'control' .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, runtime-error, sharepoint-2013

I have customized a master page in SP 2013, adding a jquery library(vs:1.11.3) to the `.html` master page as well as some custom script for pulling in HTML content.

Custom Code reference in master page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#sideNavBox').empty().load('https://pageiampullingin.html');
$('#sideNavBox').css('display', 'block');
});
```

The page I'm pulling in has its own script links that act on the DOM elements for the page I'm pulling in. This code works, even though I'm getting an error:

> "Unable to set property 'control' of undefined or null reference".

When I hit F12, occurs under `ScriptResource.axd`, `{Sys.UI.Control ... a.control=this}`. I've tried different methods for `.load()` but still getting this error. Again, HTML is pulled in and script works but can't figure out this error. When I block the `.load` function, the error goes away. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am pulling the HTML and placing it in the #sideNavBox, a SP2013 dom element (left nav).

Comment: Links in master page:                                                                  <!--SPM:<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="~sitecollection/SiteAssets/MyFolder/jquery.js" OnDemand="false" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" />-->       <!--SPM:<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="~sitecollection/SiteAssets/MyFolder/myscript.js" OnDemand="false" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" />-->

Answer (score 0):

This line is causing that error: `$('#sideNavBox').empty()`

Not sure what you are trying to achieve. Remove the line and check. The error should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but...

He's trying to replace the sharepoint left nav with custom content. I'd try this.

```
$('#sideNavBox').html("").load('https://pageiampullingin.html');
```